# Would installing a solid state drive improve my load time in Rainbow 6: Siege?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

I have a Ryzen 2600x and a 1070, but my Rainbow 6: Siege loading times is as much as five minutes. Would installing a 250GB solid state drive be beneficial towards my loading times in Rainbow 6: Siege?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not because the game needs to wait for everyone to load in to a game so, it may help some times but the likely cause for the long load times is network communication between all players. So even if you upgrade your pc and load in instantly you will still be waiting on others with slower pc's to join/spawn.

Comment: All I need is after you pick your operator, the final loading. And I’m jist talking about myself, not everyone else

Comment: @Ryan haight That's actually not true... Because he asked if it would improve "his" loading speed and of course it does

Answer (score 0):

If your loading time, after selecting an operator, is the only thing you want to improve right now, then yes, a SSD would improve your own loading time! (**Only** if your internet isn't the cause of your long loading time, you should check that first)

- If that's not the case, you should definitly look for a newer SSD with a **high reading speed**.
- You should also **check** if your motherboard got a M2 Slot, because
  if not, you'll need to go for a SATA SSD.
- Then you need to **reinstall** the game on your SSD.